# Accessing VideoView from another class in android

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I want to access videoview from another class. If I do so getting exception

```
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4607)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:835)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
at android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(VideoView.java:198)
at android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(VideoView.java:187)
at com.network.video.player.MainVideoActivity.PlayNext_Video(MainVideoActivity.java:452)
at com.network.video.player.ConnectToServer$HandleClientThread.Delete_file(ConnectToServer.java:116)
at com.network.video.player.ConnectToServer$HandleClientThread.run(ConnectToServer.java:244)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Can anybody tell me how to access a view from another class??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following method to access the view.

```
runOnUiThread(Runnable ac)
```

To do that pass the activity where the view is located to the class.

Eg:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {

    //access here

  }
});
```